# Sum of statistics for every player (goals/assists/cards etc.)

Tags: php, sql, pdo, statistics, sum

I'm trying to create a page that displays statistics for every player. A sum of total goals, assists, yellow cards, red cards etc.

The details are stored in the matchdetails you can see below:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| player_id      | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| match_id       | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| season         | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| player_present | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| player_away    | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| goals          | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| assists        | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| yellowcards    | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| redcards       | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+-----------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
| player_id | match_id | season    | player_present | player_away | goals | assists | yellowcards | redcards |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
| 3         | 1        | 2011-2012 | 1              | 0           | 0     | 0       | 0           | 0        |
| 4         | 2        | 2011-2012 | 1              | 0           | 0     | 2       | 1           | 0        |
| 4         | 1        | 2011-2012 | 1              | 0           | 0     | 0       | 0           | 0        |
| 1         | 2        | 2011-2012 | 1              | 0           | 4     | 0       | 0           | 0        |
| 1         | 1        | 2011-2012 | 0              | 1           | 0     | 0       | 0           | 0        |
| 2         | 1        | 2011-2012 | 1              | 0           | 2     | 0       | 1           | 0        |
| 2         | 2        | 2011-2012 | 1              | 0           | 1     | 2       | 0           | 1        |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
```

The thing I want to achieve is to see a row for every player in which his total matches played (player_present)
, total matches away (player_away), total goals, total assists, total yellow cards and total red cards are being displayed.

The following code I'm using already displays the total goals scored, but it sums the amount of goals scored by all the players. I want it to show a sum of every detail for every player.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(goals) AS goals, 
player_id
FROM matchdetails
ORDER BY player_id ASC
"; 
$results = $db->query($sql); 

echo "<table border='0' id='stats' cellpadding='0' cellspacing ='0'>
foreach ($results as $row) {    
    echo "<td class=''>" , $row['player_id'] , ' ' , "</td>"; 
    echo "<td class=''>" , $row['goals'] , "</td>";
}
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(goals) AS goals, player_id
FROM matchdetails
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY player_id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GROUP BY` if you want to use `SUM`.

```
SELECT SUM(goals) AS goals, player_id
FROM matchdetails
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY player_id ASC
```

Also, not sure if copy/paste error or not, you are missing a closing quote in your code:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(goals) AS goals, 
player_id
FROM matchdetails
ORDER BY player_id ASC
"; 
$results = $db->query($sql); 

echo "<table border='0' id='stats' cellpadding='0' cellspacing ='0'>";
foreach ($results as $row) {    
    echo "<td class=''>" , $row['player_id'] , ' ' , "</td>"; 
    echo "<td class=''>" , $row['goals'] , "</td>";
}
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The missing closing quote is indeed a copy/paste error.

Comment: @Joost: No problem. If my answer is correct, you should accept it as correct by clicking the large green tick under the vote count of this answer. Only accept it if it is indeed the correct answer!

Comment: I still had to wait a few minutes before I could accept it :p